# Python: comparing columns in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, iteration

I am writing a program that creates a file by an add_to_file function and then another program takes that file as input.

the file has 4 columns: name, start position(s), description, end position(s)

what the program is supposed to do, is read the file into a numpy array and create plausible "motion-sequences" by essentially creating an array that will have at least one of the end positions in a motion to be the same as at least one of the start positions in the motion that would follow

```
def make_sequence(size,array):
    count = 0
    sequence = [array[0]]
    result = [array[0,0]]
    for row in array[1:size]:
        if row[1] == sequence[count][3]:
            sequence.append(row)
            result.append(row[0])
            count += 1
        else:
            pass
    return result
```

what this is doing, is it's taking the array made from the file and making a new array (result) such that the new array just the names of the movements, but only movements that next to eachother will flow because their starting positions are the exact same as the ending positions of the prior motion! Here is my issue:

Some movements can start and end in a variety of positions, and what I have written can only take 1 starting and 1 ending position per motion.

**Question:** How could I make it so that if the string for the position values were comma separates values ie(a,b,c,d), it would be able to iterate through them and compare them from start to end so that the function will return all motions that flow?

Edit:

Here is an example of what I want my code to be able to do

input:

```
row_1 = ["Name1", "1,3,4,5", "Description", "2"]
row_2 = ["Name2", "5,3", "Description", "4"]
row_3 = ["Name3", "2", "Description", "1"]
row_4 = ["Name4", "1", "Description", "7,3"]
row_5 = ["Name5", "3", "Description", "5,9,4"]
row_6 = ["Name6", "2", "Description", "7"]
row_7 = ["Name7", "7", "Description", "2"]
row_8 = ["Name8", "1", "Description", "4"]
row_9 = ["Name9", "4", "Description", "2"]
data = np.array((column_index,row_1,row_2,row_3,row_4,row_5,row_6,row_7,row_8,row_9))
print make_sequence(7,array)
```

output:

```
[Name1,Name3,Name4,Name5]
```

You get this output because it starts automatically with row_1, which has name: "Name1", then it reads the next row and if that row has a starting position that is the same as the ending position as the previous row that was appended to the correct sequence, it's name will be appended to the result array.

And it only does this for the first 7 rows since the input was 7 for size

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense without a sample input and what your expected output should be.

Comment: I edited it as such, make sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two questions here. One is about data processing: how to extract the required information from the raw data file. What you want is the names (column 0), the start position (first element of column 1), and the end positions (last element of column 3). This might look like:

```
import numpy as np

dat = np.array([["Name1", "1,3,4,5", "Description", "2"],
    ["Name2", "5,3", "Description", "4"],
    ["Name3", "2", "Description", "1"],
    ["Name4", "1", "Description", "7,3"],
    ["Name5", "3", "Description", "5,9,4"],
    ["Name6", "2", "Description", "7"],
    ["Name7", "7", "Description", "2"],
    ["Name8", "1", "Description", "4"],
    ["Name9", "4", "Description", "2"]])

#since you only want the 7 initial columns
dat = dat[0:7,:]

#extract second and fourth columns
c1 = dat[:,1]
c2 = dat[:,3]
names = dat[:,0]

#get the start position via string manipulation
startpos = []
for item in c1:
    startpos.append(item.split(',')[0])

startpos = np.array(startpos).astype(np.int32)

#get the end position via string manipulation
endpos = []
for item in c2:
    endpos.append(item.split(',')[-1])

endpos = np.array(endpos).astype(np.int32)
print startpos
print endpos
```

Cool. Now you just need to follow startpos and endpos, like so:

```
def followpath(a1,a2):
    needle = 1
    path = []
    for ii,item,newneedle in zip(np.arange(a1.size)+1,a1,a2):
        if item == needle:
            path.append(ii)
            needle = newneedle
    return np.array(path) - 1

thepath = followpath(startpos,endpos)
print names[thepath]
```

This gives me:

```
['Name1' 'Name3' 'Name4' 'Name5']
```